# spread operator in component react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having trouble wrapping my head around the spread operator when used in the following context:

```
const renderField = ({input, label, type, meta: {touched, error, warning}}) => (
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} />
      {touched &&
        ((error && <span>{error}</span>) ||
          (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

in this case, is it taking all the props and setting them as input.*propname* ?

Comment: And see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youre using [JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) in your components. If you look at the linked article, JSX is basically just a wrapper around `React.createElement`. Whenever you're using braces in JSX, you're actually executing a regular JavaScript statement.

So, in your case, what actually happens (simplified) is the following:

```
React.createElement('input', {placeholder: label, ...input})
```

If your `input` variable contains other props, like `value`, then those props will be added to the original props object (`{placeholder: label}`), as per the [spread operator specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

[The spread syntax is also documented in the JSX explanation article.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes)

Answer (score 8):

Yes! When you spread `input`, your component automatically gets its attributes.

Let's say your `input` is:

```
const input = {
  type: 'text',
  value: 'new value',
  placeholder: 'Type anything'
}
```

After spread, your rendered component is going to be:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Type anything" value="new value" />
```